Can we pick another question for the tour page?
The current question on the tour page is was What are the common ice-breaker sentences in Chinese?.  I see multiple issues with it:

It functions as an advert for ChineseHulu.com.
The question is vague; it's an "everyone can give an answer" question.
The OP does not show their prior research.
None of the answers contain reliable references.

It's not a good example of high-quality content.
Question: Can we pick another question for the tour page?

It seems we must pick from a short list; it'll show two short answers and a comment.  I tested out a few examples, and I feel the best option is: Does Chinese have an equivalent to “Person A”?
Having tested it out, I found that many of the options are inappropriate, e.g., they're about swear words, contain some politics, are low-quality, or the comments are "welcome to the site...".  From the available options, I feel the above is the best choice (I particularly like how an answer with a reference is voted above one without).
I've changed this "for now" to get an idea of what it's like.  If you like it, great.  Otherwise, I went through them all, and the realistic alternatives are:

What is the difference in meaning between 应变 and 适应 here？

What is the difference between 餐馆 and 饭店? Is 饭店 used for restaurant or hotel?

Take away (when ordering food): is it 带走 or 打包?

What is the meaning of 真是的 if we are okay with the "As a native Chinese speaker" comment showing up

Difference between 别 and 不 if we are okay with ChineseHulu.com showing up once

What is the difference between 做 and 作? if we are okay with an answer beginning "As an extension to Flake's answer".


